# Comparing paired and unpaired samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, paired-data

I have data from three groups of participants: Group 1, Group 2, and Group 3. Participants in Group 1 have their performance recorded on Task A and Task B. Participants in Group 2 have their performance captured only on Task A. And participants in Group 3 have their performance captured only on Task B. I want to determine whether the average in participants' performance difference across Task A vs B for people in Group 1 is statistically different (less than) the average in participants' performance difference across Tasks A and B for the people in Groups 2 vs 3. What would be the best statistical test for this comparison?

If I have a table with average performances by group on each task type, it would look something like this

| Group | Task Type | Average Performance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | -2 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | A | -6 |
| 3 | B | 6 |

I want to be able to say that 2 - -2 is statistically less than 6 - -6

Comment: Could you state your hypothesis more specifically? For instance, do you wish to compare Group 1 to Group 2 on task A and Group 1 to Group 3 on task B? Do you wish to determine whether Group 1 has a lower average on both tasks or just one?  Or do you mean something else?  In what sense do you have the "paired" samples mentioned in the title?

Comment: I want to compare the average difference in performance for people in Group 1 across task A and task B to the average difference in performance for people in Group 2 vs Group 3 (across tasks A and B). I have paired samples in the sense that for people in Group 1 I have their performance on both task A and B.

Comment: Wait--how do you propose to compare Groups 2 and 3 when they have *nothing in common?*  Are you implying it makes sense to compare scores on the two tasks?

Comment: I don't just want to compare Groups 2 and 3 - I want to compare the difference in performance between Groups 2 and 3 to the difference in performance across Group 1. The setup is somewhat similar to a joint vs separate evaluations task where people in Group 1 do both task A and B and people in Groups 2 and 3 separately do each type of task. I want to see if there is a difference in how people do across types of tasks depending on whether they did them together or separately. You can imagine the two types of tasks are very similar (e.g. estimating the number of candies in jar A vs B).